# How to validate history data?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

Currently we are reading date using calendar instance for picking last one month record using sparksql. Now we need: In case of extra events being added to previous day we must also be able to manually insert summary start and end dates, in case we need manual re run of job for a previous time period:
e.g: a manual re run table could look like this:

```
rprtng_period_type_cd  summary_start_date summary_end_date  summary_iv
M                         2018-01-01      2018-01-31        2018-01
D                         2018-03-05      2018-03-05        2018-03-05
D                         2018-03-27      2018-03-27        2018-03-27
```

This should tell the job to calculate a monthly summary for Jan18 and two daily summaries, one for 05 march and one for 27 march

The job should take `summary_start_date` `summary_end_date` and ensure that only events with an `event_dt` between those two dates are only included in calculations.

My current code snippet looks like:

```
def execute(): Dataframe = {
  //log files
  val hivecntxt = SparkContextLoader.hiveContext
  val eventsourceTable= cusotmermetricConstants.source_table

  // Calendar information
  val abc = Calendar.getInstance
  abc.add(Calendar.month, -1)
  var month = abc.get(Calendar.MONTH)
  var year = abc.get(Calendar.YEAR)
  var fileMonth = month + 1
  var monthStr = if (fileMonth<=9) {
    monthStr ="0" + fileMonth.toString
  } else {
    monthStr = fileMonth.toString
  }

  //testing purpose
  monthStr = "11"
  year = 2016
  val monthlyEventDf = hiveContext.sql("select * from " + referenceDB + " ." + eventsourceTable + "where(unix_timestamp(event_Dt, "yyyy-mm"))")=unix_timestamp("' +year+ "-"+"monthstr"+"',+'yyyy-MM'))")
  val uniquedf = monthlyEventDf.repartition(col("event_Id")).withColumn("rank",rank().over(Window.partitionBy("event_Id").orderBy(desc("somevalue")))
  val monthlyEventfinal = monthlyEventDf.persist(StorageLevel.Memory_AND_DISK)

  return monthlyEventfinal
}
```

Where can we edit our requirement in current module
Looking for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` function to select records in range like below

```
//Input df

+---+----------+----------+
| cd|start_date|  end_date|
+---+----------+----------+
|  M|2018-01-01|2018-01-31|
|  D|2018-05-03|2018-05-03|
|  D|2018-03-27|2018-03-27|
+---+----------+----------+

//Parameter startDate and endDate
val endDate="2018-05-03"

val endDate="2018-05-03"

//Filter condition
df.filter(s"start_date>='$startDate' and end_date<='$endDate'").show

//Sample Output: 
+---+----------+----------+
| cd|start_date|  end_date|
+---+----------+----------+
|  D|2018-05-03|2018-05-03|
|  D|2018-03-27|2018-03-27|
+---+----------+----------+
```

I hope this will help you, If you want to do any calculation on filtered records then you have to pass columns to `udf`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion manoj.I am new to spark SQL so my silly quetion is will only using filter statement will ask my spark job to rerun for these check ponts along with what we are doing right now.  I will share a piece of code with you today if you need

Comment: Your query is not looking correct -- sql("select * from " + referenceDB + " ." + eventsourceTable + "where(unix_timestamp(event_Dt, "yyyy-mm"))")

Comment: Heyy i have edited that..my current flow is giving me o/p but what i need help on is about how to make job manually insert these details which i have shared in table format and ask job to run as many times as many rows have been added

Comment: Looking for suggestions if anyone can help me iut in thus