# How to drop duplicates considering only subset of columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6

I use Spark 1.6 and am doing inner join on two dataframes as follows:

```
val filtergroup = metric
  .join(filtercndtns, Seq("aggrgn_filter_group_id"), inner)
  .distinct()
```

But I keep getting duplicate values in `aggrgn_filter_group_id` column. Can you please suggest some solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Spark < 2.0

Consider `distinct` on a dataset with the column(s) to drop duplicates on followed by an inner join on the column(s).

```
// don't use distinct yet
val filtergroup = metric
  .join(filtercndtns, Seq("aggrgn_filter_group_id"), "inner")

// take unique aggrgn_filter_group_ids
val uniqueFilterGroups = filtergroup
  .select("aggrgn_filter_group_id")
  .distinct

// Inner join to remove duplicates from the source dataset
filtergroup.join(uniqueFilterGroups, Seq("aggrgn_filter_group_id"), "inner")
```

The price is to execute an extra `select` with `distinct` and `join`, but should give you the expected result.

### Spark >= 2.0

The following solution will only work with **Spark 2.0+** that came out with support for `dropDuplicates` operators and allows for dropping duplicates considering only a subset of columns.

Quoting the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@distinct():org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]):

> **distinct(): Dataset[T]**
>   Returns a new Dataset that contains only the unique rows from this Dataset. This is an alias for `dropDuplicates`.

`distinct` or `dropDuplicates` simply drop the row duplicates comparing every column.

If you're interested in a specific column, you should use one of the `dropDuplicates`, e.g.

```
val filtergroup = metric
  .join(filtercndtns, Seq("aggrgn_filter_group_id"), "inner")
  .dropDuplicates("aggrgn_filter_group_id")
```

When you specify a column or a set of columns, `dropDuplicates` returns a new Dataset with duplicate rows removed, considering only the subset of columns.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157163/how-to-validate-history-data seeking your help on this topic