# Hiw to insert column values of a dataframe in loop

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have my piece of code where through my job i am getting last one month records.now i need a logic where i can insert manual start date and end date in a dataframe and from that dataframe i can ask my job to fetch records based on start and end date provided in that dataframe..now if i have 4 rows my job should execute 4 times fetching records for evry time interval.[you can have my current code flow and logic in mentioned link ][1] [How to validate history data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157163/how-to-validate-history-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can achieve this by first using map function over each column values

```
recorddf = record.map(col=> col(0),col(1),col(2))

recorddf.collect.foreach(row=> {
row_1.tostring=a;
row_2.tostring=b;
row_3.tostring=c;
} )
```

now we can pass these strings to execute function of our main class